# How to access Unix root or /usr directory using Mac OS X Finder point-and-click interface?

Tags: macos, unix, root

From the Terminal application window, where I enter Unix commands:

```
$cd /usr

$pwd

/usr
```

Is it possible to navigate to this /usr directory and access it like any other folder, using the Mac OS X point-and-click interface? I mean, by selecting the hard disk icon on the Mac desktop and navigating through the Mac hierarchy of folders until I can select the same files that Unix would display under /usr..?

```
$ls -F

X11/        bin/        lib/        llvm-gcc-4.2/   sbin/       standalone/
X11R6@      include/    libexec/    local/      share/
```

I have looked and tried every way that I can think of, but I can't figure out how to do this. The reason that I want to do it is that I think that there are certain jars (like Selenium) that would most logically be placed in the tree that descends from /usr but if I were to locate these jars on the /usr tree, I don't know how to select the jars as External Jars on the Eclipse Project Java Build Path. (Going right back to my original question.) I have put the Selenium jars in another directory where I can get to them from Eclipse, but shouldn't I have the flexibility to locate them on the /usr tree?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How i can see hidden files on finder on a MAC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685179/how-i-can-see-hidden-files-on-finder-on-a-mac)

Comment: Also, there is more detailed information available on this on the apple StackExchange site: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/how-can-i-view-hidden-files-in-the-finder

Answer (score 9):

1. Open the finder
2. at top of the screen click on "Go" option
3. Select "Go to folder" option. Its second last option
4. In the popup, write the path of directory u want to access

Hope that helps

or simply after you the finder, press following keys

`command+shift+G`